# App crash in landscape using alias resources

Tags: android

It's really quite a simple app. This app should say Portrait when in portrait mode and landscape when in landscape with the help of alias resources.

I will explain in step by step what I did.

1. I created refs.xml file in res/values with the following code:

   ```
   <resources>
      <item name = "activity_dualfragment" type="layout">@layout/activity_main</item>
   </resources>
   ```
2. I created refs.xml file within the res/values-land with the following code.

   ```
   <resources>
      <item name = "activity_dualfragment" type="layout">@layout/activity_main_land</item>
   </resources>
   ```
3. I created the activity_main_land layout in layout folder with the text "landscape".
4. Finally, I assigned alias resource in the MainActivity.java in the onCreate method.

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_dualfragment);

So what is wrong? Please help.

UPDATE:
okay the error was due to floating icon in the Main Activity which I removed and the error is gone and now app doesn't crash. BUT what happens is when my device is in portrait before I run app it displays Portrait even if I change it's orientation to landscape but if my device is in landscape then it shows landscape even if I make it portrait. So what is happening? @nigam

Comment: why my code is not getting displayed?

Comment: thanks @Nigam Patro. how do you add code?

Comment: Removed the resources tag and it worked.

Comment: @nigam thanks. Could you identify problem why app is crashing?

Comment: What is the crash you are getting? Please post the logcat error.

Comment: okay the error was due to floating icon in the Main Activity which I removed and the error is gone and now app doesn't crash. BUT what happens is when my device is in portrait before I run app it displays Portrait even if I change it's orientation to landscape but if my device is in landscape then it shows landscape even if I make it portrait. So what is happening? @nigam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved the problem mentioned in the Update. It was this line of code in the manifest file that was causing the problem.
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
After I removed it now my app is showing different layouts based on orientation using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line in your manifest file under activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

and  get the orientation of the current screen using:

```
int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    //code for portrait mode
  Log.d("Orientation", "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
} else {
    //code for landscape mode
  Log.d("Orientation", "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
}
```

Comment: Please Review my question again after code is showing. I want to change layout using alias resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separated layout for both orientations. Layout version will be assigned automatically by Android system. You can place TextView with different text depend on orientation version.

Layout files have to have the same name but have to be placed to different sub directories. You can create this using Android Studio by Right Click -> New -> New Resource File -> qualifier Orientation as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to change layout using resource alias? I know there are other ways but the project I'm creating needs this trick to work.

Comment: Unfortunately @soche123 the way I described is the only sure way of creation orientation versions of the layout I know.